# Screen reader reads the year 1965 as "one nine six five"

Tags: html, date, accessibility, screen-readers

I have the `alt` attribute as `alt="Henry Lawrence's X-ray from Brandon General Hospital from May 7, 1965."`, but when the screen reader hits the year it reads it "1-9-6-5", instead of "19-65".

I've thought about spelling it out "nineteen-sixty-five" in the `alt` text, but since screen readers like VoiceOver also present the `alt` text, this might not be the best option. **How would I go about fixing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to leave as is. Different text-to-speech engines will read it different ways, so another JAWS (or other screen reader) user with a different TTS engine may hear it verbalized properly. Since you can't control how it will be verbalized across different TTS engines, the best you can do is give it an accurate label.

I especially recommend against changing the label to something less linguistically meaningful like "19 65." Consider JAWS users with Braille displays, for example -- this will look strange on the Braille display. It will also look strange to sighted users who see the alt text.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you replace the alt value like this:

```
 alt="Henry Lawrence's X-ray from Brandon General Hospital from May 7, year: 19 65."
```

If you want it to be read like that

or you could write it all in text:

```
 alt="Henry Lawrence's X-ray from Brandon General Hospital from May seventh, year nineteen  sixty-five."
```

Here is the documentation regarding the jAWS readeR and how it reads date and time: http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/tests/screen-readers/date-time/

Its difficult to give you the best answer withouth knowing which reader you're aiming at. If not aiming to one just all screen readers I think the first 2 alternatives are a good workaround.

Comment: I'm just working with the built in VoiceOver on the Mac. Leaving a space between the two numbers still reads it 1-9-6-5. Spelling it out does work. I have less experience with the better screen readers like Jaws or Dragon. The funny thing about the example link you provided is that VoiceOver skips over them, so I can't actually hear what works.